# Macbook pro heater

Tags: 18.04, macbook-pro, temperature

I came here to have some solution. I have a MacBook pro 2014 with Ubuntu 18.04.1 everything is fine except the heating of the pc.
Can you give your opinion about that (found the solution).
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the macfanctrl on? Can you elaborate a little bit about how and where you use the laptop? (e.g. lids closed or not, when this happens, etc.)

Comment: Hello sorry for my late answer. I try too use macfanctrl the problem is the fan make noise. I'm all time in the library and it bothers. I use my computer many time for programming and a little bite for design with gimp. thanks

Comment: Thanks for providing more details. If the macfanctrl is on and the problem persists, unfortunately I don't have a definite answer for you. I however can safely claim that for some reason, ubuntu is more "power hungry" than the Mac OSx or Windows, which mainstream machines are designed for. Particularly, using an older device, like the 2014 macbook pro probably amplifies the issue.